# Namespacing module method definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, pg

I accidentally came across this piece of code in Ruby's [Postgresql gem](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/blob/master/lib/pg.rb#L55):

```
### Convenience alias for PG::Connection.new.
def self::connect( *args )
  return PG::Connection.new( *args )
end
```

I played around a bit and turns out that this thing is used just like a normal module class method (it's called like this: `PG.connect`). In fact we could instead say `def self.connect ( #args ) ... end` and it would work just the same.

Since `self::whatever` is a first for me I'm wondering what exactly does `self` namespaces in such a context and what is its true purpose in this case. Can anyone help shed some light on this?

Comment: It's equivalent to `def self.connect`.

Comment: When you put code inside of a class/module definition, it runs just like any other Ruby code. The only real difference is the value of self.

As you can see below, self points to the class or module that's in the process of being defined.

class Ghost
  self == Ghost # => true
end 

module Mummy
  self == Mummy # => true
end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::` is the scope resolution operator. So `self::connect` resolves `connect` from self. Which means that its equivalent to `self.connect`. You can see how it works from this very contrived example:

```
class Foo; end

class Bar
  def Foo::baz
    "Hello World"
  end
end

puts Foo.baz # "Hello World"
```

Of course we could also just use `def Foo.baz` to get the exact same result.

Using double colons for method definition is discouraged by the [Ruby Style guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#double-colons):

> Do not use :: to define class methods.
>
> ```
> # bad
> class Foo
>   def self::some_method
>   end
> end
>
> # good
> class Foo
>   def self.some_method
>   end
> end
> ```

Its also not recommended for anything other than referencing constants and constructors:

> Use :: only to reference constants (this includes classes and modules)
>   and constructors (like Array() or Nokogiri::HTML()). Do not use :: for
>   regular method invocation.

Comment: `So self::connect resolves connect from self. Which means that its equivalent to self.connect` did the trick. So I guess the whole point of this being discouraged by the style guide is because we can define methods belonging to different classes/modules from within different classes/module which makes the code a mess, right?

Comment: You can do that without the scope resolution operator as well. The reason its discouraged is probably just readability. `::` implies that we are resolving a constant and not just passing a message to a recipient (which is actually whats happening). The message here is `define_method(:connect) do |*args|; ... end` and `self` is the recipient.

Comment: Defining methods belonging to different classes/modules is just generally discouraged as bad OOP since it violates encapsulation.

Answer (score 3):

`::` is, in some situations, somewhat equivalent to `.`. (I will leave out a precise definition in which *exact* situations it is equivalent and to what degree, because I freely admit I don't fully know it myself, nor is it well-documented.)

Here is an example of where `::` and `.` behave differently:

```rb
module Foo
  def self.Bar
    'method'
  end

  Bar = 'constant'

  def self.Qux; end
end

Foo.Bar
#=> 'method'

Foo::Bar
#=> 'constant'

Foo::Bar()
#=> 'method'

Foo.Qux

Foo::Qux
# NameError (uninitialized constant Foo::Qux)

Foo::Qux()
```

[Note: this is not a perfect example, since this is about the message sending side of things whereas your example is about the method definition side of things. I believe on the method definition side, they are 100% identical since `def` never defines a constant and thus there is no ambiguity.]

All Style Guides heavily advocate against this usage, from strongly advising against the message sensing part of it to flat out forbidding both usages of it. The main reason for this is the fact that the two behave differently for message sends, and this may lead to confusion. It is also simpler to explain the conceptual difference between method lookup (dynamic, upwards in the inheritance chain) and constant lookup (first static, lexically outward, then dynamic, upwards in the inheritance chain) when not using the same operator for both.

The typical style used by many Rubyists is:

- NEVER use `::` for singleton method definition, always use `.`.
- ALWAYS use `::` for referencing singleton methods in documentation, never use `.`.
- ALWAYS use `.` for usage examples of message sends (including singleton methods) in documentation, never use `::`.
- NEVER use `::` for message sends (including singleton methods), always use `.`.

Those last two are sometimes softened to allow for methods that are supposed to return modules or classes, and to allow for methods that act as factories (e.g. [`Nokogiri::XML`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri.html#XML-class_method)) to be invoked via message sends that "look like" constant lookup, (e.g. `Nokogiri::XML('<root/>')` instead of `Nokogiri.XML('<root/>')`).

There was a [feature request](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8377) for removing this usage of `::`, but it was [rejected](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby/wiki/DevelopersMeeting20130809#Deprecate-for-method-calls-8377) mostly because of backwards-compatibility concerns.

Comment: Nice examples but @max in his comment pretty much nails it: "The message here is `define_method(:connect) do |*args|; ... end` and `self` is the recipient". Thus if `def self::some_method(*args) ... end` equals `define_method(:some_method) do |*args|; ... end` then it's like sending a message to `self` to define a method there which makes total sense.